# Use One Express Rest API Server For Both React-js Application and Android Application

Tags: android, reactjs, express, mern

I have two client applications 
one is browser application(reactjs) and another is an android application. 
few crud operations to be performed in both the applications using MongoDB as a database.

1. Can i use one rest API built using express js for both of them or
   there are any other better ways to do ?

Comment: yes you can do so

Comment: Yes. Most web and android applications of the same company share the same rest API. For example, following your case, you can host REST api to any server and use the end points to perform operations in any client. Android, IOS, Web or anythhing.